# Octopus Deploy: Set deployment limitation between multiple environments

Tags: octopus-deploy

I have multiple environments on Octopus Deploy and everything working fine. I want to add one limitation but I cannot find way how to solve this.

Example I have CD, QA and Staging environments. From TFS it is always deployed to CD environment automatically. From CD to QA is deployed manually via Octopus, and also from QA to Staging.

Now I want to set limitation on Octopus that nobody can promote directly from CD to Staging. I want that CD environment only promote from CD to QA! Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lifecycles in Octopus 2.6 is designed to solve this exact problem.

Comment: Thanks for navigation @DamianM ; I found here good post https://octopusdeploy.com/blog/2.6